# Clone RAID5 from one controller to another?

Tags: raid5, clone, acronis

i have a question concerning cloning a Raid5.

System: HP ML350 with a RAID controller, 2 Bays.
Bay 1 Raid5 3x2TB 
Bay 2 RAID5 3x600 SAS

The 3 SAS Disks in Bay 2 need to be swapped, it is predicted that they all fall out soon. I have 3 new 600 SAS Drives, but dont want to swap them one by one because i dont want to copy the disk failures to the new disks.(HP Support told me not to do it)

Backup isnt working, i have tried but it wont boot and i need to fix this quickly. So this option is cancelled. I'll take care of the Backup once the disks are ok again.

So what I thought what should work:
1.Take out the three 2TB Disks from Bay1.
2.Insert the new 3x600 SAS Disks into Bay1 and create a new Raid5.
3.Clone the 3x600 SAS Disks from Bay 2 to the 3x600SAS Disks in Bay1
4. Take out 3x600 SAS Disks from Bay 2 and put in the 3x600SAS Disks from Bay 1
5. In Bay1, put back the 3x2tb Disks

Do you guys have experience with that?
EDIT:
If yes, woul it work with common known cloning software?

I have experience with a software but just cloning single disks and not from one Array to another.

Comment: Product/tool-recommendation questions are off-topic for ServerFault.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Asking for **a** product that will complete a certain task is not off topic and you can't just use any old cloning software because you need one with drivers for the raid.

Comment: Sry! I edited it!

Comment: Oh man you really should not be using RAID 5 with those 2TB disks - nobody's using it for large volumes these days due to some dull maths that can kill your data - we haven't for years in fact. Try to use R1/10 or R6/60, nothing else works long term.